# How do I do a "for ...in ...." loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, logging, loops, console

```
simple_client = new simplegeo.PlacesClient('gHPQAUFbHHL3sHcfSqaetBMskrKZY5');
        var place_query = "starbucks";
        simple_client.search({{ browser_lat }}, {{ browser_long }}, { q: place_query }, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
            } else {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

            }
        });
```

In this code, I log the entire JSON (in a string format) in the console.  However, what if I want to loop through "data", and log each one?

Comment: Have you tried logging the data object itself, like `console.log(data)`?  Firebug at least gives you a nice object tree; you don't have to write dump routines.

Comment: I recommend using `console.dir(data)` for viewing data structures and objects.

Comment: @Raynos, `console.dir()` rocks, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Like so:

```
for(var key in data) {
   if(!data.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
   //do something with key or data[key]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jQuery you can use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/).

```
$.each(data, function(i,v){
    alert(v);
});
```

Comment: You should totally drop that and use jQuery instead.

Comment: @Raynos Actually I think that jQuery is overkill here, so he should totally drop it and use jQuery instead.

Comment: I'll spoil the fun: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Comment: @Raynos: ah, ok.  I only suggested jQuery because someone else suggested for...in, so I wanted to suggest a different option.  Also, this question is tagged `jQuery`.

Comment: @Rocket The answer fine. it just feels like an appropiate joke. On that note I'll recommend underscore.js

Comment: @all I hate using jQuery when using vanilla JS will do the job just fine.

Answer (score 1):

If your using [underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) you can use [`_.each`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#each)

```
_.each(data, function(value, key, data) {
    // do something with value
});
```

Comment: You know, you should totally drop that and use jQuery.